# sharing traces in multiple subplots in Plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plot, scatter-plot, plotly

I need to plot a data set with the same structure as in the Iris flower data set with Plotly.js. It should look like [Mike Bostock's scatterplot matrix](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3213173). While getting the effect shown in the link is pretty simple, I am having a problem with the legend - I want to be able to switch on/off whole series (such as specific species in the Iris flower example) simultaneously on all subplots by clicking the corresponding legend item. Currently, I am adding traces for each subplot separately, but this results in separate items for each subplot in the legend (16 x 3 instead of just 3, one for every species), so clicking on an item works only for one subplot at a time. Does Plotly.js give any way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do so with the [`legendgroup`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#scatter-legendgroup) trace attribute.

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/MKbqPB

Comment: This works superbly for Python. Make sure to have separate `legendgroup`s for each distinct `legend` item!